# How to add class to parent's parent's div in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dinamically builded list of tests:

```
<script id="TestsTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
        <article class="tests-main">
            <section class="tests">
                <div class="test" ng-repeat="test in tests">
                    <p>Question {{ test.number }}:</p>
                    <div ng-repeat="answer in test.answers">
                        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in answer">
                            <p><button ng-click="processAnswer(value, $event)" class="btn" >&#9675 {{ key }}</button></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </article>
    </script>
```

and I want to add a class to the div(class="test") in which button was pressed.

I am familiar only with the jQuery and I can think of only this approach:

```
$scope.processAnswer = function(isRight, event) {       
    isRight ? $scope.count++ : $scope.count--;
    event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.addClass('hide');
}
```

How to do it in Angular style ?

**EDIT:**
My solution:

Use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

```
<div ng-class="($index==selectedIndex) ? 'hide' : 'test'" ng-repeat="test in tests">
```

controller:

```
$scope.selectedIndex = -1;
$scope.processAnswer = function(isRight, index) {
        isRight ? $scope.count++ : $scope.count--;
        $scope.selectedIndex = index - 1; //$index starts at 0;
    }
```

where `index` is `test.number`

Comment: Probably should use a directive. Alternatively you could use `ng-class` and on `ng-click` set a variable on `test`

Comment: @Tristan There is a difference ? If I manipulate the DOM so, but in the directive, whether it will Angular way?

Comment: Dom manipulations should not exist in controllers, services or presentation layer. The reason is for "clean separation of concerns". Directives are reusable, testable, and easier to handle dependencies. It depends on how important these practices are to your project. As I mentioned, you can very easily use `ng-class` in the template without even involving the controller, but it's not recommended for the before mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use `ng-class` to apply the class when you set a boolean to `true`. For example :

```
 <div class="test" ng-repeat="test in tests" ng-class="{'hide' : onProcessAnswer}">
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.onProcessAnswer = false;
$scope.processAnswer = function(isRight, event) {
        ... 
        $scope.onProcessAnswer = true;
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
angular.element(event.target).parent().parent().addClass("hide");
```

Manipulating dom in html is not recommended . You should do your dom manipulation only in directives.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Angular is a library to make coders do less dom option.

You can use data-bind feature to achieve most request mostly.

If you do want to get a parent element and add an attribute, just use jQuery or pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try as simple

```js
$element.parent().addClass('default-class');
```